# How to setup so I can set a breakpoint in ASP.NET MVC 4 source?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to set a breakpoint in the source code for MVC 4.

Here are the steps I took:

- Cloned the Git repo at git clone https://git01.codeplex.com/aspnetwebstack.git
- Compiled in visual studio
- executed: `sn -Vr *`
- Added an MVC 4 project to the solution
- Removed the reference to System.Web.Mvc and added it back from the local project in the solution

Still, when I run it I get the error about the assembly signing.  I admit I have never had to do much with assembly signing - but from what I understand the `sn` command disabled that.

Any suggestion on how I can go about successfully setting it up so I can step through the code?

**Error I'm getting:**

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc' or one of its
>   dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The
>   assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not
>   fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131045)

Is the the "one of its dependencies" part that is screwing me up maybe? Am I making a wrong assumption maybe that I can just reference one of the locally built assemblies? (I'm just guessing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [build instructions](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Building%20from%20Source) mention downloading and running (from an elevated command prompt) `SkipStrongNames -e`, the executable being available [here](http://aka.ms/skipsn).

However, I think it's more useful to be able to debug the framework and third-party libraries right in your project, without having to mess with the source of those libraries. You just need the debug symbols and to [configure VS accordingly](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/07/04/stepping-into-asp-net-mvc-source-code-with-visual-studio-debugger.aspx). Regarding symbol servers, if you can, I'd start using [symbolsource.org](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Home/VisualStudio) for better coverage.

Comment: thanks for the advice about sybolsource - i didn't know about that!

Comment: i never did figure it out but I think you deserve the credit for helping me out and offering an alternate solution... maybe something about how strong naming works has changed i don't know..

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I couldn't help more with the specific problem, but once you get debugging using symbols only working, I'm confident you'll be much better off anyways.